# SharePoint 365 Custom MetaData and Graph API - Error 400

Tags: vb.net, metadata, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to use the Graph API and Visual Basic to change an or update custom metadata / list fields in SharePoint 365.

```
My code to complete the update is below
 Public Sub UpdateFileMeta(ByVal strFileID As String)


        'Dim fileId As String = "<file-id>"
        Dim metadata As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
               {"certificate_x0020_no", "iop"}
        }

        ' Set the endpoint URL for updating file metadata
        Dim endpointUrl As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" & siteId

        ' Serialize the metadata values to JSON format
        Dim metadataJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metadata)

        ' Create a new HTTP client and add the authorization header
        Dim client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strAccessToken)

        ' Create a new HTTP request with the endpoint URL and HTTP method
        Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(New HttpMethod("PATCH"), endpointUrl)

        ' Set the request content to the metadata JSON
        request.Content = New StringContent(metadataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

        ' Send the request and get the response
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result

        ' Print the response status code and content
        Console.WriteLine("Response status code: " & response.StatusCode.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Response content: " & response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)

    End Sub
```

My column for the line {"certificate_x0020_no", "iop"} is called Certificate No but using Graph Explorer it is referenced as Certificate_x0020_No and I believe that the Graph API needs the value to be lower case.

I am passing the below to the module:

```
"<our tenant'.sharepoint.com,<Site ID>,/drives" & /<drive id>" &
                       "/root:/Certificates+/<sub folder>+/<sub folder>/file name:/"
```

When the code runs the respomse is below:

```
Response statusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  request-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  client-request-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
  Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2023 21:56:31 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}}
```

Nothing in the sharepoint site is updated. If I change the code to reflect a standard field e.g

```
    {"certificate_x0020_no", "iop"}
```

to

```
    {"description", "Its a ball"}
```

The code runs and the response starts with StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK' and the SharePoint metadata updates.

Can you update custom MetaData?